# How can PyTorch-like automatic differentiation work in Rust, given that it does not allow multiple mutable references?

Tags: rust, backpropagation, automatic-differentiation

I'm mostly an outsider trying to understand if Rust is appropriate for my projects.

There are frameworks that do automatic differentiation in Rust. Specifically, [candle](https://github.com/huggingface/candle), and some other projects, I think, somehow do it in a way that's similar to PyTorch, according to their description.

However, I know that Rust does not allow multiple mutable references. And it seems like that is what's needed for PyTorch-like automatic differentiation:

```py
x = torch.rand(10) # an array of 10 elements
x.requires_grad = True

y = x.sin()
z = x**2
```

***Both*** `y` and `z` must keep mutable references to `x`, because you might want to backpropagate them, which will modify `x.grad`. For example:

```py
(y.dot(z)).backwards()
print(x.grad) # .backwards() adds a new field (an array) to x, without modifying it otherwise
```

So how can similar behavior be implemented in Rust, given that it does not allow multiple mutable references?

Comment: The obvious way would be an internal [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html). Or you could just not have the variables be proper stack variables in the first place, always having to refer to them through `some_manager_object.set_variable("a", 42f32)` or similar.

Comment: @Caesar Thanks. I wonder if `RefCell` would work for walking backwards in an arbitrary directed acyclic graph. It seems like without some extra machinery, you might end up doing multiple mutable borrows of the same object.

Comment: `RefCell` indeed *isn't* for that, it should be applied to make your variables mutable, but the relationships between them have to be expressed separately. This kind-of falls into https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/ categories. You can do this with `Rc`s, but there's tons of pitfalls. Most sane approaches to working with graphs in Rust boil down to having that `some_manager_object`, be it as a [petgraph](https://docs.rs/petgraph/) or a [bump allocator](https://docs.rs/bumpalo/) - which makes cyclic references possible.

Comment: @Caesar *"which makes cyclic references possible"* The compute graph here is acyclic by its nature. New variables need refs to the ones they were computed from, but not the other way around.

Comment: Right... I'm not quite sure how to explain it. You can have structs with references to stuff that has the same lifetime as the structs themselves. Like [this](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#LyoKW2RlcGVuZGVuY2llc10KYnVtcGFsbyA9ICIqIgoqLwoKI1tkZXJpdmUoRGVidWcpXQpzdHJ1Y3QgTm9kZTwnYT4oT3B0aW9uPCYnYSBOb2RlPCdhPj4pOwoKZm4gbWFpbigpIHsKICAgIGxldCBidW1wID0gYnVtcGFsbzo6QnVtcDo6bmV3KCk7CiAgICBsZXQgbXV0IGhlYWQgPSBOb25lOwogICAgZm9yIF8gaW4gMC4uMTAgewogICAgICAgIGhlYWQgPSBTb21lKCYqYnVtcC5hbGxvYyhOb2RlKGhlYWQpKSk7CiAgICB9CiAgICBkYmchKGhlYWQpOwp9Cg==). (Could use stack alloc here, but difficult for DAGs.)

Comment: Since Rust is Turing Complete, anything is possible. I'm no expert, but even if a language didn't support cyclic references, you could always (i) write your own garbage-collected heap, or a simplified version, (ii) use a single hashtable `Dict[str, object]` to hold all references, and use the `str` keys (which can certainly be duplicated) to indirectly express cyclic relationships, rather than the `object` values directly.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Your (ii) is essentially what petgraph does. (Just not with strings. Oh the overhead. ;)) But it's also quite a bit less ergonomic than working with e.g. dumpalo: You'll always need to go through that `Dict` (or `HashMap`), and you'll need to manually manage which entries are live or manage GC roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the rust compiler enforces that there can only be one mutable reference to a value at a time, but there is an escape hatch: the [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) pattern.

This pattern allows programmers to construct data structures for which the rules are checked at **run time** instead of compile time.

The standard library provides a number of containers that implement interior mutability, with different usage patterns suitable for different scenarios. Key examples are:

- [`RefCell<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html#refcellt), which allows run time borrow checking for single threaded usage
- [`RwLock<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html), which allows run time borrow checking for mutliple threaded usage
- [`Mutex<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), which only allows one reference at a time to its contents

There are others - see the module level documentation for [`cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html) and [`sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/index.html).

How does this apply to candle? Let's take a [peek under the hood](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/955e00b2e895c6e53f9348b1dd672ee4ebcf8f53/candle-core/src/tensor.rs#L25):

```rust
pub struct Tensor_ {
    ...
    storage: Arc<RwLock<Storage>>,
    ...
```

The contents of the storage that backs the tensor are protected by an `RwLock`. In fact there are some comments in the code immediately above this which describes the reason for the choice of this particular solution - worth a read.

Not only that, but this is in turn wrapped in an [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) - which means that it is in fact a heap allocated, reference counted value. There can be multiple 'owners' of this value, and it will only be deallocated when the last owner goes out of scope.

How is this used in the case of backpropagation? Well, the [`backward()`](https://docs.rs/candle-core/0.3.0/candle_core/struct.Tensor.html#method.backward) method of `Tensor` does not directly modify the tensor, rather it returns a [`GradStore`](https://docs.rs/candle-core/0.3.0/candle_core/backprop/struct.GradStore.html) containing the computed gradients. A `GradStore` may in turn be consumed by an [`Optimizer`](https://docs.rs/candle-nn/0.3.0/candle_nn/optim/trait.Optimizer.html). `Optimizer` is a trait, with a couple of different implementations, so let's take a look at the [`SGD`](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/main/candle-nn/src/optim.rs#L35) optimizer:

```rust
    fn step(&mut self, grads: &candle::backprop::GradStore) -> Result<()> {
        for var in self.vars.iter() {
            if let Some(grad) = grads.get(var) {
                var.set(&var.sub(&(grad * self.learning_rate)?)?)?;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
```

OK, so the gradients are here being applied to some `Var` instances - what are these (defined [here](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/main/candle-core/src/variable.rs#L10))?

```rust
pub struct Var(Tensor);
```

Ok, a wrapper around a `Tensor`. And how does the [`set` method](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/main/candle-core/src/variable.rs#L121) do it's job? This line is key:

```rust
let (mut dst, layout) = self.storage_mut_and_layout();
```

That gives us a mutable variable that seems to represent the destination for the set operation. What does this [`storage_mut_and_layout()`](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/955e00b2e895c6e53f9348b1dd672ee4ebcf8f53/candle-core/src/tensor.rs#L2151) method do?

```rust
let storage = self.storage.write().unwrap();
```

Ahah! It calls the [`write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#method.write) method on the `RwLock` we saw above, inside which the storage lives. The documentation for this method says:

> Locks this RwLock with exclusive write access, blocking the current
> thread until it can be acquired.
>
> This function will not return while other writers or other readers
> currently have access to the lock.

So in summary:

- The `backward()` method itself does not seem to modify the input `Tensor`, but it returns a data structure containing the gradients
- The gradients get applied to the `Tensor` using an `Optimizer`.
- The `Optimizer` uses the `set` method to alter the `Tensor`, which under the hood gets mutable access to the `Tensor`'s data storage using the `write()` method on the `RwLock` that is protecting it.

Answer (score 2):

The way to provide seemingly multiple mutable references in Rust is via [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/interior-mutability.html) which allows for mutation through shared references. There are still requirements imposed by Rust that disallow mutation *at the same time* but there are a few ways this can be ensured and thus there are a few types that provide interior mutability generically: [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). They build off of [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) as the core primitive that tells the compiler that `&` doesn't necessarily mean immutable for the contained value.

If we look at candle's source, the fundamental `Tensor` contains an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) which allows multiple tensor "handles" to refer to the same *value* - `Arc` provides shared ownership ([source](https://docs.rs/candle-core/0.3.0/src/candle_core/tensor.rs.html#70)):

```
pub struct Tensor(Arc<Tensor_>);
```

The hidden inner `Tensor_` type looks like this ([source](https://docs.rs/candle-core/0.3.0/src/candle_core/tensor.rs.html#25-45)):

```
pub struct Tensor_ {
    id: TensorId,
    // As we provide inner mutability on the tensor content, the alternatives are:
    // - Using a mutex, this would have the highest cost when retrieving the storage but would
    //   prevent errors when concurrent access takes place. Mutex would also be subject to
    //   deadlocks for example using the current code if the same tensor is used twice by a single
    //   binary op.
    // - Using a refcell unsafe cell would have some intermediary cost, borrow checking would be
    //   verified dynamically, but the resulting tensors would not be send or sync.
    // - Using an unsafe cell would have the lowest cost but undefined behavior on concurrent
    //   accesses.
    // Ideally, we would use Arc<Storage> for tensors on which we don't plan on modifying the data
    // and Arc<Mutex<Storage>> for tensors where the data could be modified, e.g. variables but
    // that's tricky to encode in the current setup.
    storage: Arc<RwLock<Storage>>,
    layout: Layout,
    op: BackpropOp,
    is_variable: bool,
    dtype: DType,
    device: Device,
}
```

Which conveniently has a comment weighs the options for interior mutability of `storage` for us. The `RwLock` is the peice that allows multiple handles to access and/or mutate the tensor's contents.

So when the backpropagation happens, it accesses the relevant tensors' `storage` by acquiring a `RwLockReadGuard` in order to access the data to do the operation and then releases those guards before doing anything with the resulting tensor to avoid deadlocking (since the `RwLock` would block if mutation was attempted when an existing guard is held).

It appears the library does not make use of this interior mutability, since it prefers to create new tensors instead of mutating existing ones, unless it is a variable that *should* be updated to reflect the new data. In this case it acquires a `RwLockWriteGuard` to swap out the data with the new value and again quickly releases the guard.

Its hard to give exact lines for this in candle's source since there are many layers for the backpropagation, storage operations, and keeping track of the results. I also can't give a concrete demonstration with formulas since I'm not well versed in the subject. But I hope this is clear nonetheless and can help you with your own ventures.

Comment: Beat me by 3 hours! That'll teach me to type up an answer and then go for lunch!